# How do I improve the performance of a symfony admin generator page?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony admin generator page where each row makes several function calls and, therefore, several trips to the database.

I added a query to `table_method` and used some joins but it doesn't reduce the number of queries executed on my page.

What's a person supposed to do to improve performance here?

Comment: Doctrine: If you're using the `select()` method in your `table_method` query, are you sure you've selected any joined tables here as well as using eg `leftJoin()`?

Comment: If you're joining onto the tables and you're still seeing additional queries, you're not selecting some of the values. Narrow down which calls are triggering queries and ensure those values are being selected.

Comment: Or, you have manual dql calls somewhere in Model class, probably.

Comment: Post your table_method code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your query linked to your "table_method" must have all the fields that show otherwise you're probably ignoring some kisa field or your query did not add in fields related to samples

Symfony according to the manual that is done to reduce the number of queries as follows:

```
   
 # apps/backend/modules/job/config/generator.yml
config:
  list:
    table_method: retrieveBackendJobList
```

```
 
    // lib/model/doctrine/JobeetJobTable.class.php
class JobeetJobTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function retrieveBackendJobList(Doctrine_Query $q)
  {
    $rootAlias = $q->getRootAlias();
    $q->leftJoin($rootAlias . '.JobeetCategory c');
    return $q;
  }

  // ...
```

Comment: The performance increase is just amazing! (Nothing like reading the documentation properly!)

Comment: I've selected this as the best answer although I should note that I haven't tried what's suggested here. This issue ended up becoming a non-priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable some filters on foreign key, they have their own specifics requests, not based on table_method.